# mail() function and Microsoft 365

Tags: php, email

I'm using PHP's `mail()` function for sending "forgot password" links and reports to admins. When I'm testing it with Gmail everything works fine. But when I send emails to the Microsoft 365 mailboxes, mails don't appear even in the Junk folder.

What should I do?

UPD

I tried with headers and "Return-path" additional parameter. My code looks like:

```
        $to      = 'my_email@corporate_domain.com';
        $subject = 'test';
        $message = 'test';
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "To: Tamara <my_email@corporate_domain.com>" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: Sender <sender@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: Sender <sender@domain.com>'. "\r\n";
        $headers .=  "Return-Path:<Sender@domain.com>"."\r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-r sender@domain.com");
```

And I finally got bounce email, which says:

Service unavailable; Client host [5.166.*.68] blocked using Blocklist 1, mail from IP banned; To request removal from this list please forward this message to delist@messaging.microsoft.com and include your ip address.

But no messages was delivered to this email, even to this domain. How my IP can be already banned?

Comment: Do you receive bounce messages?

Comment: Can you post the code your using for the mail function?

Comment: @Tamara This [link](http://allinthehead.com/retro/315/php-mail-and-the-path-of-no-return) describes how to setup the SMTP envelope - ensure the email account associated with the 'From' address will accept any bounce messages

Comment: @StevenFarley I'm just testing,so I don't use any headers:

mail("myemail@company-domain.com", "test", "test")

Comment: @Tamara Try setting the From address - I think Office 365 is likely to reject your message if it has an invalid From address

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would to first remove any custom content in the headers parameter, and see if just plain emails pass thru first. If it's failing and you're sending plain text emails, I'd suggest checking for a PTR record on the address that the mail server is sending from. You should be able to see this in the header of the email you received in gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Try sendind a test email using this:

```
$to      = 'myemail@company-domain.com';
$subject = 'test';
$message = 'test';
$headers = 'From: yourValidEmail@example.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: yourValidEmail@example.com' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

If this works and you now see your emails in your *junk/spam* folder I would suggest looking into setting a [PTR record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) and also making sure you have the correct reverse dns settings for your domain name to point to your servers ip address. See [Reverse DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup)